# Prevention for Open Redirect Problem in Salesforce

Tags: apex, url, redirect

I am facing some issue of "Open Redirect", is there any direct solution or document which may help me.

```
pagereference p = new pagereference(returnUrl);
return p;
```

here Security issue is

> Open Redirect Vulnerability
>
> An open redirect is an application that takes a parameter and
>   redirects a user to the parameter value without any validation. This
>   vulnerability is used in phishing attacks to get users to visit
>   malicious sites without realizing it.

I have redirect urls in alomost each class of mine.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about your problem, what is it that you are trying to do and what is the error or the result you can't achieve? Otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Add whats returnURL variable in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you are looking for can be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Arbitrary_Redirect

> The general solution to the problem is to constrain the range of URLs to which your redirector will redirect. Constraining URLs by hostname is easy; the best way to do it is by keeping a list of known-good hostnames and checking that a URL’s hostname matches one in the list. You can also limit by known-good schemes and by known-good paths (perhaps using a regular expression).